# Cordova cannot find plugins in Netbeans

Tags: cordova, netbeans

I used nodejs to install cordova version '3.5.0-0.2.7'.  The app compiles fine in netbeans.  I have a plugins folder at the same level as the www folder.  When I run the app I get a message for all of my plugins.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (11:09:29:715 | error, network)
  at

```
http://localhost:8383/AppName/plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification/www/local-notification.js
```

It is looking for the plugins folder, but the files are in the js folder.  How do I have it point to this folder?